# Svg polygon doesn't scale with browser window

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design

hey i have some Svg elements consisting each out of a polygon shape. see the following code:

```
<body>
<svg class="svgRules" width = "100%" height="200">
    <polygon class="opmaakPoly" id ="p1" points="500,0 1920,0 1920,200 600,200"/>
</svg>

<svg class="svgRules" width = "100%" height="200">
    <polygon class="opmaakPoly" id="p2" points="600,0 1920,0 1920,200 700,200"/>
</svg>
</body>
```

with the following style:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.svgRules{
    float: left;
}

.opmaakPoly{
    stroke:#F0c;
    fill: #FFF;
    stroke-width:2px;
}
```

now when i scale the browser window the polygon shapes dont scale accordingly i tried setting the points to percentages but that didnt seem to work. so how do i make the polygon element scale with the browser window?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n6nurrnh/)

Comment: What is the question..? The SVG is set to `100%` of its container `body` already.. Your `body` has no `width`... But looks fine : https://jsfiddle.net/n6nurrnh/

Comment: sorry half the text has dissapeard let me fix that so u can see the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oke thanks to rainforce15 and maxshuty i figured out how to do it properly!

you indeed need to add the:

```
viewBox="0,0,1920,1080" preserveAspectRation="none"
```

but you need to make the viewBox the size of the polygon shape inside otherwise it will deform the polygon shape.

so instead of using:

```
viewBox="0,0,1920,1080"
```

use

```
viewBox="0,0,1920,200"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" preserveAspectRatio="none"
```

or similar to your `svg` tag - the viewbox should have the your desired (`svg-internal`) size, while `preserveAspectRatio` will allow it to scale properly - check the available values if "none" doesn't create the desired result.